# Why won't action up register?

Tags: android, andengine

I'm running a scene update handler to increase the scale of my sprite while the scene is being touched. It is supposed to stop when the user lifts his finger, but my action up never registers. The sprite just keeps increasing in size until the screen is touched again, at which point the old sprite stops growing and the new one starts. Any ideas why?

```
scene.registerUpdateHandler(new IUpdateHandler() {

        @Override
        public void reset() {         
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
            if(fillerNum>-1){
                if(filler[fillerNum].active){
                    mPhysicsWorld.unregisterPhysicsConnector(mPhysicsWorld.getPhysicsConnectorManager().findPhysicsConnectorByShape(filler[fillerNum].sprite));
                    mPhysicsWorld.destroyBody(filler[fillerNum].body);

                    filler[fillerNum].sprite.setScale(filler[fillerNum].scale+=pSecondsElapsed*.5);

                    filler[fillerNum].body = PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(mPhysicsWorld, filler[fillerNum].sprite, BodyType.DynamicBody, FIXTURE_DEF);
                    mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(filler[fillerNum].sprite, filler[fillerNum].body, true, true));
                }
            }               
        }
    });






@Override
    public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene, TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {
         if(this.mPhysicsWorld != null) {
                if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()) {
                    createFiller(pSceneTouchEvent.getX(), pSceneTouchEvent.getY());
                    return true;
                }
                if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionUp()){
//Never executed
                    Log.e("Action UP", Boolean.toString(filler[fillerNum].active));
                    createStationaryFiller();
                }
            }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: fillerNum is simply a reference (integer) to keep track of which sprite is active and how many are on the scene.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As it turns out, I needed to add an isActionUp method in the onAreaTouched method of the creation of my sprite as well as having it in the onSceneTouchEvent. Without the former, the sprites kept growing until another touch was added. Without the latter, you could drag your finger off of the sprite and it would still grow.

Comment: Now why in the world did this get downcast?

Answer (score 0):

you are registering an update handler! Which means continous calling of this onUpdate method as long as your scene is registered with Engine. It will only stop when your fillerNum becomes less then -1. You need to look at behaviour for filler number.

Comment: That is incorrect. It stops when filler[fillerNum].active is false.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ZoomExample` for your reference, when you touch the scene, the camera will zoom in smoothly, you just need to replace the zooming portion with your code to scale up the sprite:

```
scene.setOnSceneTouchListener(new IOnSceneTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(final Scene pScene, final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {
            switch(pSceneTouchEvent.getAction()) {
                case TouchEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    //sprite.setScale() code
                    break;
                case TouchEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    //sprite.setScale() code
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Many a people have broken their head over this problem! You will smack yourself when you get your mistake!
Check your `onSceneTouchEvent()` method. You `return false` in the end.
The return value of false for the method tells the TouchListener that the TouchEvent(action down) being performed by the user is INVALID! thus the TouchListener will STOP REGISTERING ALL FOLLOWING EVENTS(action move, action up... etc.) !

Thats why the code in the second `if` statement is never executed!
All you gotta do is change `return false` to `return true`, telling the touchlistener that you want following events to be registered.

Such a silly problem yet so frustrating!